# Remove consecutive duplicate values in an Array - Arduino/ Java

Tags: java, arrays, arduino

Im using Ardunio but happy for solutions in Java as this may help me understand.

I have an array `stateX[]` of length 50 and it will hold values similar to:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1......
```

I'd like to know how I can remove the duplicate values from the array, which are **next** to each other. So the output would become a smaller array with elements:

```
0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1
```

Obviously this smaller array will alter in size, so I'm unsure about that. And also how to detect the repeated values.

Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: as said just use a loop to iterate over your array with an index then increment it while the next value is equal to the current (which you can store in your final array)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a "systematic" methodology, but here's one way you can do it:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,0,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1};
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

lst.add(array[0]);

for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(array[i]!=lst.get(lst.size()-1)) lst.add(array[i]);
}

int lstSize = lst.size();
int[] revisedArray = new int[lstSize];
for(int i = 0; i < lstSize; i++) revisedArray[i] = lst.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works in-place and doesn't use any java Lists, both these characteristics should be helpful in porting to Arduino/C. It has a complexity of O(a.length).

Note that as the input/output array is not resized, and values are removed, it ends up being too large. The returned value `newSize` indicates the length of the solution, i.e. only the first `newSize` values in a are relevant after the method is called.

```
public static int removeAdjacentDuplicates(int[] a) {
    int newSize = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        // check if the current value differs from the preceding one
        if (a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            a[newSize++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not know Ardunio , but I made the following class in Java, it is pretty self explanatory, hope this may help, dont hesistate to ask any questions!:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Duplicates {

    static ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //Creating an arrayList with random numbers from 0 to 5, note that it will work with any numbers.
        for(int index = 0 ;  index <= 1000 ; index++)
        {
            Random myRandom = new Random(); 
            int x = (int) (myRandom.nextDouble() * 5); 
            ints.add(x);

        }

        //Calling my method to remove dupliates next to another
        ArrayList<Integer> cleanedList = removeNextToAnotherDuplicates(ints);

        //Displaying it in the console
        System.out.println(cleanedList.toString());

    }

    public static  ArrayList<Integer> removeNextToAnotherDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++)
        {
            boolean continueFlag = true;

            // j = j because I do not want to always increment my position, since I would skip some due to the fact that I remove duplicates
            for( int j = i + 1; j < list.size() && continueFlag ; j = j)
            {
                //Showing each iterations.
                System.out.println("i("+ i +") :" + list.get(i).intValue() + "   j("+ j +") :" + list.get(j).intValue());

                if(list.get(i).intValue() == list.get(j).intValue())
                {
                    list.remove(j);
                }
                else
                {
                    continueFlag = false;
                    j++;
                }

                //Showing each iterations.
                System.out.println("flag: "+ continueFlag);
                System.out.println(list.toString());

            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```